# Errror "Index Out of Range" at WinBUGS

Tags: r, maps, winbugs

I have converted the ArcGIS Shapefile to SPlus file format using R code to input at WinBUGS.

```
      library(maptools)

       library(sp)

       usa_counties <- readShapePoly("E:\\USA_Counties.shp", IDvar = 
        "CNTY_FIPS")

       # Convert to WinBUGS S-Plus format
      splus_data <- sp2WB(as(usa_counties, "SpatialPolygons"), filename 
       = "E:\\USA_Counties.txt")
```

Although I have conducted the task perfectly and imported it into WInBUGS for the USA States, unfortunately, I failed to import the USA Counties Splus file in WINBUGS and it shows the error.

```
          index out of range

         MapsSplus.Import   [00000569H] 
.centreX    REAL    0.0
.centreY    REAL    0.0
.i  INTEGER 10000
.id INTEGER 3221
.map    MapsMap.Map [029B0F80H] 
.name   ARRAY 80 OF CHAR    "area20"   ...
.numReg INTEGER 3221
.ok BOOLEAN TRUE
.polygon    MapsMap.Polygon [02BAB8B0H] 
.pos    INTEGER 19
.region MapsMap.Region  [02A0CAB0H] 
.s  TextMappers.Scanner Fields
.string ARRAY 80 OF CHAR    "area20"   ...
.x  ARRAY 10000 OF REAL Elements
.xScale REAL    1.0
.y  ARRAY 10000 OF REAL Elements
.yScale REAL    1.0
      MapsImporter.Import   [00000164H] 
.f  Files.File  NIL
.fileName   Files.Name  ""   ...
.item   Meta.Item   Fields
.loc    Files.Locator   NIL
.m  Models.Model    [029910F0H] 
.map    MapsMap.Map [029B0F80H] 
.ok BOOLEAN TRUE
.pos    INTEGER 0
.protocol   ARRAY 256 OF CHAR   "MapsSplus"
.res    INTEGER 0
.s  TextMappers.Scanner Fields
.string ARRAY 120 OF CHAR   "MapsSplus.Import"
.text   TextModels.Model    [029910F0H] 
.v  MapsImporter.RECORD Fields
.wr Stores.Writer   Fields
    StdInterpreter.CallProc   [0000047AH] 
.a  BOOLEAN FALSE
.b  BOOLEAN FALSE
.c  BOOLEAN FALSE
.i  Meta.Item   Fields
.imported   ARRAY 256 OF CHAR   ""   ...
.importing  ARRAY 256 OF CHAR   ""   ...
.mn Meta.Name   "MapsImporter"
.mod    StdInterpreter.Ident    "MapsImporter"
.object ARRAY 256 OF CHAR   ""   ...
.ok BOOLEAN TRUE
.parType    INTEGER 3
.pn Meta.Name   "Import"
.proc   StdInterpreter.Ident    "Import"   ...
.res    INTEGER 0
.v  StdInterpreter.ProcVal  Fields
.vi StdInterpreter.ProcIVal Fields
.vii    StdInterpreter.ProcIIVal    Fields
.vr StdInterpreter.ProcRVal Fields
.vri    StdInterpreter.ProcRIVal    Fields
.vrii   StdInterpreter.ProcRIIVal   Fields
.vrr    StdInterpreter.ProcRRVal    Fields
.vrri   StdInterpreter.ProcRRIVal   Fields
.vrrii  StdInterpreter.ProcRRIIVal  Fields
.vrs    StdInterpreter.ProcRSVal    Fields
.vrsi   StdInterpreter.ProcRSIVal   Fields
.vrsii  StdInterpreter.ProcRSIIVal  Fields
.vs StdInterpreter.ProcSVal Fields
.vsi    StdInterpreter.ProcSIVal    Fields
.vsii   StdInterpreter.ProcSIIVal   Fields
.vsr    StdInterpreter.ProcSRVal    Fields
.vsri   StdInterpreter.ProcSRIVal   Fields
.vsrii  StdInterpreter.ProcSRIIVal  Fields
.vss    StdInterpreter.ProcSSVal    Fields
.vssi   StdInterpreter.ProcSSIVal   Fields
.vssii  StdInterpreter.ProcSSIIVal  Fields
      StdInterpreter.Command   [0000131CH] 
.left   StdInterpreter.Ident    "MapsImporter"
.ptype  INTEGER 3
.right  StdInterpreter.Ident    "Import"   ...
    StdInterpreter.CallHook.Call   [00001441H] 
.ch CHAR    0X
.e  ARRAY 64 OF CHAR    ""   ...
.errorMsg   ARRAY 2 OF CHAR " "
.f  ARRAY 64 OF CHAR    ""   ...
.g  ARRAY 64 OF CHAR    ""   ...
.hook   StdInterpreter.CallHook [029F0050H] 
.i  INTEGER 33
.i0 INTEGER 0
.i1 INTEGER 0
.id StdInterpreter.Ident    "Import"   ...
.par0   Dialog.String   ""   ...
.par1   Views.Title ""   ...
.proc   ARRAY 33 OF CHAR    "MapsImporter.Import('MapsSplus')"   ...
.res    INTEGER 0
.s0 Dialog.String   "MapsSplus"
.s1 Dialog.String   ""   ...
.type   INTEGER 3
.x  INTEGER 0
        Dialog.Call   [00002FC8H] 
.errorMsg   ARRAY 2 OF CHAR " "
.proc   ARRAY 33 OF CHAR    "MapsImporter.Import('MapsSplus')"   ...
.res    INTEGER 0
     StdDialog.HandleItem   [0000084BH] 
.i  StdDialog.Item  [02AC0020H] 
.res    INTEGER 0
     HostMenus.HandleCustomMenu   [0000209EH] 
.i  StdDialog.Item  [02AC0020H] 
.id INTEGER 410
.m  HostMenus.Menu  [02ABF6C0H] 
   HostMenus.MenuCommand   [0000221AH] 
.id INTEGER 410
.lParam INTEGER 0
.old    INTEGER 65539
.res    INTEGER 0
.wParam INTEGER 410
.wnd    INTEGER 1116432
    Kernel.Try   [00003A61H] 
.a  INTEGER 1116432
.b  INTEGER 410
.c  INTEGER 0
.h  PROCEDURE   HostMenus.MenuCommand
   HostMenus.ApplWinHandler   [0000378AH] 
.Proc   PROCEDURE   NIL
.hit    BOOLEAN FALSE
.lParam INTEGER 0
.message    INTEGER 273
.res    INTEGER 0
.s  ARRAY 256 OF SHORTCHAR  2X   ...
.w  INTEGER 0
.wParam INTEGER 410
.wnd    INTEGER 1116432
 <system>   (pc=776E2E52H,  fp=0061FA94H)
  <system>   (pc=776D3C25H,  fp=0061FB8CH)
 <system>   (pc=776D24E4H,  fp=0061FC08H)
   <system>   (pc=77746D0FH,  fp=0061FC10H)
   HostMenus.Loop   [00003BDEH] 
.done   BOOLEAN FALSE
.f  SET {0..5}
.n  INTEGER 1
.res    INTEGER 0
.w  HostWindows.Window  NIL
 Kernel.Start   [00002B8CH] 
.code   PROCEDURE   HostMenus.Loop
```

Comment: Could anyone please answer the Question?